# How should a subnet`s Address Block look like to get a valid `ipv4 address block`

Tags: ipv4, subnet, vnet

I want to add a subnet in azure VNet.

How should a subnet`s Address Block look like to get a valid`ipv4 address block` that convers the address range?

```
10.3.11.0 - 10.3.11.255
```